# Arcmap Label annotations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I am working on labeling features. I tried the annotation labels, but I have decided that it is not what I wanted. How do I change it back or delete the annotation label?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Activate the labels again in the feature properties. They were deactivated when you converted them into annotations.

To delete the annotations it need to be clear what you have? If you have graphics elements then you go to "Edit" - "select all elements" and press delete.

When you have an annotation-layer in a database you just delete the layer via the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert symbology to annotation, you can store in map, or in database.
[image]

If you decided that you do not like it, just go to layers and in data frame properties, go to annotation groups tab, and there you can simply delete your annotation group.

[image]